# data visualization with d3.js in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I have implemented with d3js my code and I wanted to visualize my data but I dont know how I continue to implement
My problem is I would like by clicking on a node, the list of publications assigned to a keyword is to be called up. Highlight the currently selected node in the visualization.

I want to display the publication list, in gray area (#selection_details) to the visualization. Display the authors, the title, and the publication year for each publication.

(actually I have some problems with change JSON structur!)

you can see my code here in [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ofcncsfL/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes in your code to add *Author*, *Title* and *Publication Year* details to the JSON data bound to nodes.

```
var repeats = Object.keys(bib).reduce((a, v) => {
  bib[v].keywords.split(/\s*,\s*/).forEach(kw => {
    a[kw] = a[kw] || {
      repeat: 0
    };
    a[kw].test = (a[kw.id])
    a[kw].repeat++;
    a[kw].title = bib[v].title;
    a[kw].author = bib[v].author;
    a[kw].year = bib[v].year;
  });
  return a;
}, {});
```

To display the publication details in the div on click of nodes, try as shown below.

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
  //Clear existing details if any
  d3.select("#selection_details")
    .select("*")
    .remove();
  //Show publication details
  var html = "<P><B>Author:</B> " + d.author + "</P> <P><B>Title:</B> " + d.title + "</P> <P><B>Year of Publication:</B> " + d.year + "</P>";
  d3.select("#selection_details")
    .html(html);
});
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ofcncsfL/2/

Comment: tnx so much, but how can i display all publication of each keywords?
In your example display just one publication!

Comment: Okay. Do you need something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ofcncsfL/3/  And what is the expected format?